# How can I set default alignment for variables with arm gcc

Tags: gcc, arm, default, memory-alignment

I'm developing an application for an arm7tdmi target.
I used to compile the code with IAR but now I switched to arm-none-eabi-gcc and I have the following problem.

```c
typedef struct
{
    uint32 nNumber;
    uint32 nPara1;
    uint32 nPara2;
    uint32 nPara3;
    uint32 nPara4;
    uint32 nPara5;
    uint32 nParax[122];
} TTXSpecial_t;

static uint8 cTelBuf[TTX_TEL_LENGTH];
```

for example when `cTelBuf` is placed @ `0x4000000A`

```c
&(((TTXSpecial_t *)cTelBuf)->nNumber)
```

returns the same address, so far everything is okay.

---

The `cTelBuf` gets filled so that `((TTXSpecial_t *)cTelBuf)->nNumber` should be `0x87654321`.

A memory dump shows:

```c
0x40000000: 00 00 04 00 00 02 0C 00 00 02 21 43 65 87 00 00 
0x40000010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

---

**The problem** is whenever I read `(TTXSpecial_t *)cTelBuf)->nNumber` the value will be `0x2004321`.
So as you can see the read is done at address `0x40000008` instead of `0x4000000A`.

---

my cflags are: `-mcpu=arm7tdmi -Os -gdwarf-2 -mthumb-interwork -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wpadded -Wstrict-prototypes -fstrict-aliasing -fverbose-asm -Wa`

---

**Question 1: How can I set a default data alignment with the arm-none-eabi-gcc**
I know that `static uint8 cTelBuf[TTX_TEL_LENGTH] __attribute__((aligned(4)));` will fix the problem in this case, but I want to set the alignment in general. How does the IAR compiler do it?

**Question 2: Is there a way to avoid this problem in general (without copying)?**
I mean: what if I want `TTXSpecial_t` struct to start at `cTelBuf+1`.
One solution could be to memcpy `cTelBuf+1` to an allocated `TTXSpecial_t` struct, but how to do it without allocating extra memory?

Comment: You probably don't declare 'cTelBuf' like that in your real code.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you have types and dont use them. The compiler knows that `TTXSpecial_t` contains 32-bit values that need to to be 4 byte aligned. The problem is that you declare your cTelBuf as byte array, where the compiler can only say that the byte accesses do not need an alignment.

So I would suggest you declare your byte array as your actual type `TTXSpecial_t` (and cast it for the byte access to your uint8), or make it a combined data type, by declaring it as union (i.e. as your `TTXSpecial_t` and `unit8` array that overlapp).

Afaik there is no generic option in gcc to change the default alignment for variables (some architectures have special -malign switches, but I thing for arm are none available), and a quick glance into the IAR doc say, that the IAR compiler behaves the same way. That means that he would align a variable of your struct type at 4 byte boundaries, but the declared byte array would only be 1 byte aligned - it seems you just got lucky that you got never problems with your code using IAR compiler - you should fix it asap as it can happen there too.